# issue with return value of service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm facing issues in returning data from Angular Service. Below is the service code....

```
app.service('Data',function(){

var accountList = [];
var currentAccount ='Test1'; //Initialization

var bookmarkAccount = function(accountName){
    accountList.push(accountName);
}
var setPassingAccount = function(Account){
    console.log('in Service : setting current account value to '+Account);
    currentAccount = Account;
}

return{
    bookmarkAccount: bookmarkAccount,
    setPassingAccount: setPassingAccount,
    currentAccount: currentAccount,
    accountList: accountList
};
});
```

I'm able to access all methods/variables from 'Data' service except "currentAccount". Getting empty value, while accessing it from controller. Below is the controller code...

```
app.controller('BookmarkController',function(Data){

 this.accountList = [];
this.accountList = Data.accountList;
this.account = Data.currentAccount; //ISSUE
Console.log('Account list object'+accountList);
Console.log('Current account selected :'+this.account);
}
```

I'm able to get all values in 'accountList', but getting empty 'currentAccount'. Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you are showing us. Somewhere else, before the controller is called, you are probably calling `setPassingAccount` with `null`, `undefined` or `''` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi @SergiuParaschiv,  Actually there are two controllers[say Ctrl1 and Ctrl2]. Controller1 is assigning value to 'currentAccount' using 'setPassingAccount' method. Controller2 is accessing it. When accessing it from Controller2, getting empty value....

Comment: As I said, the problem is not in the code you are showing us.